# Visual Studio Mac: MAUI app archive fails with three errors

Tags: ios, .net, maui

For days I am trying to archive my ios app, I set up provisioning and everything right, but when I run this command:

```
sudo dotnet publish -f:net6.0-ios -c:Release -r ios-arm64 --self-contained
```

I get three errors:

> error NETSDK1032: The RuntimeIdentifier platform 'ios-arm64' and the PlatformTarget 'x64' must be compatible. [/Users/juliustolksdorf/Projects/Skillbased/app/skillbased_prod/Skillbased/Skillbased.csproj::TargetFramework=net6.0-ios]

> /project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-ios'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0-ios' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.

> A bundle identifier is required. Either add an 'ApplicationId' property in the project file, or add a 'CFBundleIdentifier' entry in the project's Info.plist file.

Error 1 I can omit by editing the `csproj.user` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IsFirstTimeProjectOpen>False</IsFirstTimeProjectOpen>
    <ActiveDebugFramework>net6.0-ios</ActiveDebugFramework>
    <ActiveDebugProfile>iPhone 14 Pro Max iOS 16.1</ActiveDebugProfile>
    <SelectedPlatformGroup>Simulator</SelectedPlatformGroup>
    <DefaultDevice>iPhone 14 Pro Max iOS 16.1</DefaultDevice>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetPlatformIdentifier)'=='iOS'">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>iossimulator-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

and taking out `x64`. Then the error does no longer appear on archive, but I cannot build my app on emulator anymore when I do this. Great success.

Error number 2 I was never able to omit, what is especially wired is that it is talking about a sub project (middleware.data) and not the main project. What am I supposed to do with that information?

And error number 3 is just stupid; ofc I have set a bundle ID in my csproj file

```
<!-- App Identifier -->
<ApplicationId>com.skillbased.skillbasedapp</ApplicationId>
<ApplicationIdGuid>2041a417-5399-434b-95f8-83e997177fb7</ApplicationIdGuid>
```

Why does it hate me so much?

I am running this on Visual Studio Mac

I really need your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after many moons I figured it out:

First, If you have a subproject in your repo,
change the target framework from FRAMEWORK to FRAMEWORKS (with an s),
then also change the target to be on ios. That shis isnt auto included when u set the projects up is baffeling:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
```

Now, the bundle ID error is a false error. Even though you did set it up right, the error will show, just ignore it.

Next, go to your project and delete the csproj.user file entirely. Also delete ALL bin and obj folders from the repo and the sub solutions (if you have any).

Now to the fun part, the failing in provisioning:
Make sure in your keychain there is only ONE valid certificate for your project. Even when they have different names, it might confuse your mac and therefore just not find it right.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

If it looks any different, or says it isnt trusted, it will also fail.
Do not click on the certificate and put it on "ALWAYS TRUST". It MUST use application defaults.

If it isnt autotrusted, REMOVE it and create a new one.

Then make sure you also have these certificates installed:

[image]

If you dont have them, download them here:

https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/

Download all of them that expire after one year from now. (the World wide ones) Shouldnt be more than 4.

Double click them, they should show up in your keychain.

If your certificate was invalid before, it will now show as valid.

Now try building your app with the profile installed and with a release config. This will now finally prompt you for the password to your keychain.

If this is put in correctly you can finally build your app with:

```
dotnet publish -f:net6.0-ios -c:Release -r ios-arm64 --self-contained
```

Do NOT use a SUDO.

And thats it.
Easy right?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, publishing is only supported through the `.NET command line interface` at this time. To publish your app, open a terminal and navigate to the folder for your .NET MAUI app project. Run the dotnet publish command like below to create an `.ipa`:

```
dotnet publish -f:net6.0-ios -c:Release /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true /p:_DotNetRootRemoteDirectory=/Users/{macOS username}/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/
```

For more details, you can refer to [Publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/overview?view=net-maui-7.0#publish).

Secondly, when you have set your iOS app with its provisioning profile,it should generate the property group like below:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsPublishing)'  == 'true' And '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-ios'">
  <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  <CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution: John Smith (AY2GDE9QM7)</CodesignKey>
  <CodesignProvision>MyMauiApp</CodesignProvision>
  <ArchiveOnBuild>true</ArchiveOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Last but not least, you need add below to your `Info.plist` file.

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.skillbased.skillbasedapp</string>
```

For more details, you can walk through [Publish a .NET MAUI app for iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/overview?view=net-maui-7.0) and [Suggested update to the MAUI Docs on publishing](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/issues/681).

Hope it works for you.

Comment: thanks for the help, that doesnt translate to mac well tho, but I have figured out the issues